# Redirecting not logged requests to external URL with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I have a web application using spring mvc and spring security.

Not-logged requests must be redirected to a external legacy system for authentication. The external system doesn't need any parameter from the spring webapp. The legacy system would (or not) authenticate the user and put a cookie/header/parameter on a new request. Then this request will be authenticated using this cookie, header or parameter against the spring webapp.

Is there a 'right' way to do this redirection? I am thinking of implementing a completely new `AuthenticationEntryPoint` that simply sendRedirect the request to the external system.

I'm unsure about which is the 'right' way to authenticate the already authenticated request against the spring webapp. Should I use the pre-authentication framework or am I right just implementing a filter that extract the credential and authenticates it?

Thanks in advance.